# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am an intermediate Rails developer that has encountered a peculiar issue. I was trying to execute a controller method that searches through a model's columns for the distinct attributes such as the size and color using jquery ajax and ran into this stack error. It only does this when I declare an array inside the method and I have no idea how to solve it. The console displays this many times. Notice, I had rendered my partials and ajax in a view different from the routes, I did that so it'd be easier to navigate through the folders

```
  Rendered arts/colors.js.erb (496.7ms)
  Rendered arts/colors.js.erb (497.4ms)
  Rendered arts/colors.js.erb (498.2ms)
  Rendered arts/colors.js.erb (499.1ms)
  Rendered arts/colors.js.erb (501.6ms)
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 543ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".item").change(function(){
      var gender = $(".gender").val();
      var shirt_size = $(".item").val();
    //  var color = $("#colors").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "/variants/display_colors",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "js",
        data: {shirt_size, gender},

      });


    /*  $.ajax({
        url: "/variants/display_price",
        type: "GET",

        data: {shirt_size, color, gender},

      });*/
    });
  });
```

My method

```
def display_colors
  respond_to do |format|
    @colors = Variant.color_search(params).distinct.pluck(:color_code).first
    format.js{render template: "/arts/colors.js.erb"}
  end
end
```

Model

```
def self.color_search(search={})
  where("shirt_size = ? AND gender = ?", "#{search[:shirt_size]}", "#{search[:gender]}")
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match '/variants/display_colors' => "variants#display_colors", :via => :get
end
```

My View

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="design-image" style="margin: auto">
    <%= image_tag @design.image.url %>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>

    <h2 style="text-align: center">
      <%= @design.name %>
    </h2>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".item").change(function() {
          var gender = $(".gender").val();
          var shirt_size = $(".item").val();
          var color_code = $("#color").val();

          /* $.ajax({
            url: "/variants/display_colors",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "js",
            data: {shirt_size, gender},

          });*/


          $.ajax({
            url: "/variants/display_price",
            type: "GET",

            data: {
              shirt_size,
              color_code,
              gender
            },

          });
        });
      });
    </script>
    <div>
      <div class="product-options" style="color: white;">
        <%= form_for @order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
          <%= f.select :gender, ["Male", "Female"], {}, {class: "gender"} %>
            <%= f.select :shirt_size,
              @sizes,
              {},
              {class: "item"}
          %>
              <div class="price" style="color: white">

              </div>
              Quantity:
              <%= f.number_field :quantity, min: 1, max: 100, style: "max-width: 150px;" %>
                <div class="color_codes" style=" padding: 10px; ">
                  <% @color_codes.each do |t| %>
                    <div style="border: 3px solid white; margin: 2px; display: inline-block; background-color: <%= t %>; width: 50px; border-radius: 10px;">
                      <%= f.radio_button :color_code, t, class: "item", id: "color"%>
                    </div>
                    <% end %>

                </div>
                <%= f.hidden_field :art_url, value: @design.image.url %>
                  <%= f.button :submit %>
                    <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, could you ad your view code too?

Comment: @Bohdan I added the view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh my! I never thought to check the actual javascript. It was my colors.js.erb! I mistakingly left **template:** when i was rendering a partial.
I changed

```
$(".product-options").html("<%= escape_javascript(render template: '/arts/colors') %>");
```

To

```
$(".product-options").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: '/arts/colors') %>")
```

Now who would've thought to check that!

Comment: There were no mention of your templates in your question.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma That's because i didnt realize that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

can you check the item class on page?

I think there is more than one `item` class.

Try to add `id` attribute and then perform change event.

Comment: You were right about there being more than one item class but unfortunately it still gave me the same error. I gave the offender a new class and edited the ajax